# Neo4J how to aggregate and count same query results?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to do some text analysis in Neo4j and I want to write a query where it sorts the number of results in a descending order. My data is structured:

`(Word)->[next]->(Word)->[Next]` etc.

I want to write a query which says which are the most popular 3 word combinations, 4 word combinations, etc.  I tried this but it always gives a count of one for word combinations:

```
MATCH p = (w1:Word)-[r:NEXT]->(w2:Word)-[r2:NEXT]->(w3:Word)
WITH [w1.name,w2.name,w3.name] AS word_pair 
RETURN COUNT(word_pair) as frequency, word_pair
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Show an example of the input data.

Comment: Hi, this is how I loaded the data: 
WITH split(tolower("My cat eats fish on Saturday")," ") as text
Unwind range(0,size(text)-2) as i
MERGE (w1:Word {name: text[i]})
ON CREATE SET w1.count = 1 ON MATCH SET w1.count=w1.count+1
MERGE (w2:Word {name: text[i+1]})
ON CREATE SET w2.count = 1 ON MATCH SET w2.count=w2.count+1
MERGE (w1)-[r:NEXT]->(w2)
ON CREATE SET r.count = 1
ON MATCH SET r.count=r.count+1

Comment: WITH split(tolower("My Cat eats cat food on Saturdays")," ") as text
Unwind range(0,size(text)-2) as i
MERGE (w1:Word {name: text[i]})
ON CREATE SET w1.count = 1 ON MATCH SET w1.count=w1.count+1
MERGE (w2:Word {name: text[i+1]})
ON CREATE SET w2.count = 1 ON MATCH SET w2.count=w2.count+1
MERGE (w1)-[r:NEXT]->(w2)
ON CREATE SET r.count = 1
ON MATCH SET r.count=r.count+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frequency of the pattern is always one, because you pack information about it in the `count` property of the relationship. Therefore, you do not need to count the number of occurrences of a pattern, but find the minimum of this property:

Example data:

```
UNWIND ["My cat eats fish on Saturday",
        "My Cat eats cat food on Saturdays"] AS text
WITH split(tolower(text)," ") AS words 
UNWIND range(0,size(words)-2) AS i 
  MERGE (w1:Word {name: words[i]}) 
    ON CREATE SET w1.count = 1 
    ON MATCH SET w1.count=w1.count+1 
  MERGE (w2:Word {name: words[i+1]}) 
    ON CREATE SET w2.count = 1 
    ON MATCH SET w2.count=w2.count+1 
  MERGE (w1)-[r:NEXT]->(w2) 
    ON CREATE SET r.count = 1 
    ON MATCH SET r.count=r.count+1;
```

Query:

```
MATCH p = (:Word)-[:NEXT*2]->(:Word)
WITH extract(n IN nodes(p) | n.name) AS word_pair, 
     extract(r IN relationships(p) | r.count) AS counts
UNWIND counts AS count
RETURN word_pair, 
       min(count) AS frequency
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's very helphul.

Comment: @ArunasK If the answer solves your problem do not forget to accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers